# Regex replace all occurrences

Tags: c#, .net

I need to replace a string where it follows a specific string and some varying data. I need to keep the beginning and the middle and just replace the end. When I tried the code below, it replaces only the last occurance. I have tried switching to a non greedy match but then it doesn't find it. The middle could contain new lines as well spaces, letters and numbers.

```
String s = "Beginning of story. Keep this sentence. Old ending.\n";
s += s;
s += s;
s1 = Regex.Replace(s, @"Beginning of story. ([\s\S]*) Old ending.", "Beginning of story. " + @"$1" + " New ending.", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

The result is this:
Beginning of story. Keep this sentence. Old ending.
Beginning of story. Keep this sentence. Old ending.
Beginning of story. Keep this sentence. Old ending.
Beginning of story. Keep this sentence. New ending.
```

How do I replace every occurance of "Old ending."

Comment: Try adding a `$` at the end of your pattern - should match the end of each line, given your `Multiline` option.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/785745

Comment: A non-greedy match should take care of it. Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't replace anything
s1 = Regex.Replace(s, @"Beginning of story. ([\s\S]?) Old ending.", "Beginning of story. " + @"$1" + " New ending.", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: This is just an example. In my real data what I want to replace is not at the end of a line. but that gives me an idea to try.

Comment: @BrianK:  I think a non-greedy match would be `*?`, not just `?` - `?` on its own is `0 or 1`.

Comment: One thing to look out for is to escape your `.`'s as well. It probably wont matter because in most cases it will just consume the literal `.` anyway, but it is still a good idea to use `[.]` or `\.` instead.

Comment: *? for the non-greedy match worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think Kendall is bang on with the related link, [a non greedy match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ae5bf541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) e.g.

```
s1 = Regex.Replace(s, @"Beginning of story. ([\s\S]*?) Old ending.", "Beginning of story. " + @"$1" + " New ending.", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Should do the trick.

Edit:

You should also be able to change the pattern inside your capture region to be: `.*`
where `.` will match any character except the newline character.

Answer (score 7):

If all you want to do is replace `Old ending` with `New ending`, why don't you just use good old **string.Replace**?  Will be easier and faster than using regex

```
String s = "Beginning of story. Keep this sentence. Old ending.\n";
s.Replace("Old ending", "New ending");
```

**Update:**  To replace `Old ending` wherever it is preceded with `Begining of story...` then use this regex `(?<=Beginning of story.*?)Old ending`, play around with this if you have slight variations, but this should get you there

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=Beginning of story.*?)Old ending", "New ending");
```

This basically says, find and replace "Old ending" with "New ending", but only if it starts with "Beginning of story blah blah blah"

Comment: I only want to replace "old ending" where it occurs after "Beginning of story". If it occurred outside of that pattern, I don't want to replace it.

Comment: @BrianK see updated answer, the pattern I provided should do the trick