# C# / Regex - Replacing set of matches with another set of matches

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to turn this string:

> INSERT INTO [main].[sqlite_default_schema].[TableName] (**[SomeColumn],
>   [SomeOtherColumn], [Last]**) VALUES (**@param1, @param2, @param3**);

into this one:

> INSERT INTO [main].[sqlite_default_schema].[TableName] ([SomeColumn],
>   [SomeOtherColumn], [Last]) VALUES (**@SomeColumn, @SomeOtherColumn,
>   @Last**);

As a beginner in regex, i'm using this C# snippet:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(.*?\)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(commandText);
if (matches[0].Success && matches[1].Success)
{
    Regex reColNames = new Regex(@"\[\w*\]");
    MatchCollection colNames = reColNames.Matches(matches[0].Value);
    Regex reParamNames = new Regex(@"\@\w*");
    MatchCollection paramNames = reParamNames.Matches(matches[1].Value);
    if (colNames.Count > 0 && colNames.Count == paramNames.Count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Count; i++)
        {
            string colName = colNames[i].Value.Substring(1, colNames[i].Length - 2);
            commandText = commandText.Replace(paramNames[i].Value, "@" + colName);
        }
    }
}
return commandText;
```

This works but doesn't feel right. 
Is there a way to achieve the same result by using just one regex?

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex replace all occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242416/regex-replace-all-occurrences)

Comment: Imo, the solution requires 3 steps: 1 -> finding everything within () 2 -> extracting colNames from the first group found in 1. 3 -> replace params with corresponding colNames based on index in second group.

Comment: How many such queries exist? It would be far easier if you created separated queries as constant strings, or switched to an ORM.

Comment: You have a CSV string : "@Column1, @Column2, @Column3".  So use :  string csv = string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(1,3).Select(x => "@Column" + x.ToString()));

Comment: @TanveerBadar This is part of an attempt to automate the creation of Statement Constants.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are replacing all "param" text with "column". Why not start with that in the first place? If that's impossible due to some concerns you haven't mentioned see the solution below.

This will bulk replace everything in 1 line.

```
Regex.Replace(query, "param", "column", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: While true for the params, I cannot be certain of column names, as they actually represent the columns of a Table in the DB. So [Column1], [Column2], ... would be actual Names like [FirstName], [LastName], ...

Comment: Then please update the question with a better example. As pattern matching goes, that's not currently evident. I will leave this answer up for posterity.